# how can I add error message when url is empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, function, drop-down-menu

This is my code section to getting timeslots when changing the date, here I need to display error or warning message if the selected date doesn't have timeslot. but my added message still not display. What I did wrong here!

```js
function changeBookingDate() {
  var date = $('#booking-date').val();
  var doctorId = $('#doctor-list').val();
  $('#time').hide();
  if (date != null && doctorId != null) {
    console.log(date, doctorId);
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{url("bookings")}}/' + doctorId + '/' + date,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(result) {
        $('#time').show();
        if (result) {
          $('#booking-time').html('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Time</option>');
          $.each(result, function(index, data) {
            $('#booking-time').append('<option value="' + data.value + '">' + data.text + '</option>');
          });
        } else {
          showErrorMsg('The selected doctor is away on selected Date');
          $('#addBtn').prop('disabled', false);
        }

      }
    });

  } else {
    $('#booking-time').val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="new-booking-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="doctor-list">Doctor</label>
    <select id="doctor-list" name="doctor" style="width:100%" onChange="changeBookingDate()"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="booking-date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datePicker1" autocomplete="off" name="date" id="booking-date" onChange="changeBookingDate()" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="display:none" id="time">
    <label for="patient-list">Time Slot</label>
    <select id="booking-time" name="doctor" class="form-control"></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please post your html in snippets to quick solve

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Any errors in the console? Does the Ajax return what you expect?

Comment: What does showErrorMsg look like?

Comment: I have added HTML there, when I pass URL I got an empty array, in this case, I wan to get warning/error message

Comment: So what does "result" contain?

Comment: result not alert anything, It contains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean this

```js
const showErrorMsg = str => {
  alert(str)
};

function changeBookingDate() {
  var date = $('#booking-date').val();
  var doctorId = $('#doctor-list').val();
  $('#time').hide();
  if (!date || !doctorId) return;

  $.ajax({
      url: '{{url("bookings")}}/' + doctorId + '/' + date,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(result) {

    if (result && result.length > 0) {
      $('#booking-time').html('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Time</option>');
      $.each(result, function(index, data) {
        $('#booking-time').append('<option value="' + data.value + '">' + data.text + '</option>');
      });
      $('#time').show();
    } else {
      showErrorMsg('The selected doctor is away on selected Date');
      $('#addBtn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });  
}
```

If that does not work, then it is a server issue!

Comment: `result.length > 0` I just added this in if condition, Now its showing error message,
Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="date" required id="booking-date">
```

Then, if there is no value, it automatically displays the message.
Wrap it in a non-action form for automatic validation upon focus change.

Comment: That would only show upon submission of a wrapping form - it is not relevant to the question here. Kavi wants to show an error when the returned value from the ajax call is empty

Comment: Got it, my bad,

Comment: Feel free to delete the answer then